# Typeconversion in managed c++

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Hi in the second line while trying to convert from object to String array it shows compile time error as

'System::String ^' : a native array cannot contain this managed type

'initializing' : cannot convert from 'System::String ^' to 'System::String ^[]'

**code:**

```
RegistryKey ^rk = Registry::LocalMachine->OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQLServer");
String ^instances[] = (String^)rk->GetValue("InstalledInstances");
```

How to fix this ....
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last line to

```
String ^ instances = (String^)rk->GetValue("InstalledInstances");
```

(note the absence of brackets). If the key contains a multistring, use

```
array<String^>^ instances
    = (array<String^>^)rk->GetValue("InstalledInstances");
```

See the [documentation for RegistryKey.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdf576x1.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `instances` as an array type:

```
String ^instances[] = (String^)rk->GetValue("InstalledInstances");
```

Instead, declare it as a string:

```
String ^instances = (String^)rk->GetValue("InstalledInstances");
```